# Salvar após ocultar uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Uso um código Jquery para ocultar uma div, e gostaria que quando clicar no botão fechar ele salvar e impedir que seja exibido novamente para o usuário quando a página for recarregada.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".info-game--remove").click(function() {
            $('#info-game').css("display","none");
        });
});
```

Eu vi sobre cookies mas não sei como implementar nesse código,

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza da resposta, mas acredito que usar [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) seja melhor e mais simples que tentar usar cookies. Não tenho experiência com isso então não posso oferecer mais detalhes, mas o link já deve dar uma ajuda.

Comment: Estou construindo um exemplo de utilização do seu caso ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar `localStorage` para armazenar a informação se o botão irá aparecer ou não.

A primeira coisa é deixar o botão *nativamente* oculto ao carregamento da página:

```
<style>
#info-game{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Ao carregar a página, você verifica se o `localStorage` está vazio -- se estiver, você mostra o botão, caso contrário, nada será feito e o botão continuará oculto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   if(!localStorage.infogame)  $('#info-game').show();

   $(".info-game--remove").click(function() {
      localStorage.infogame = "$('#info-game').hide()";
      eval(localStorage.infogame);
   });

});
```

Não esqueça de limpar o `localStorage` quando quiser voltar a mostrar o botão:

```
localStorage.removeItem('infogame');
```

Comment: muito obrigado, esse deu certo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Como você mesmo disse, pode-se fazer isso com cookies:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".info-game--remove").click(function() {
        $('#info-game').css("display","none");
        document.cookie = "infoGameRemoved=true;"; 
    });
});
```

Veja este exemplo no fiddle: [Exemplo de cookie com JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/AnthraxisBR/sugpenkd/2/)

OBS: para testar, clique em `'executar'`, em seguida clique em `'remover'`, ai o cookie ja estará salvo, clique em `'executar'` novamente e clique em '`Mostre-me se #info-game está removido'`, sempre que clicar em executar, é como dar um ***F5***, veja que se o cookie está como true, ele não exibe, se é alterado para false, a div é exibida.

Comment: Coloquei este código mas ainda esta mostrando a div quando recarrega, será que estou fazendo certo?